# Mariadb High Disk Write

Tags: linux, mariadb

I recently set up an docker application stack (Mail server) containing MariaDB as a database.
Furthermore I noticed high (I guess?) IO write rates to my disks: (It goes up to like 40M/s)

```
Total DISK READ:         0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:        13.50 M/s
Current DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE:      13.35 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                                                             
23581 be/4 systemd-    0.00 B/s    3.90 M/s  0.00 %  0.76 % mysqld
23595 be/4 systemd-    0.00 B/s    3.00 M/s  0.00 %  0.61 % mysqld
23580 be/4 systemd-    0.00 B/s 2009.49 K/s  0.00 %  0.31 % mysqld
23578 be/4 systemd-    0.00 B/s 1271.89 K/s  0.00 %  0.27 % mysqld
23572 be/4 systemd-    0.00 B/s 1706.88 K/s  0.00 %  0.25 % mysqld
```

Since I don't know exactly how the application is build I was wondering if I could somehow find out which MariaDB processes are responsible for constantly writing?
I don't have IO issues, just wondering where all this data, that needs to be written to disk, comes from.

As per reqeust:

```
# mysql -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"|grep -vi sleep
Id      User    Host    db      Command Time    State   Info    Progress
1       system user             NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge worker     NULL    0.000
4       system user             NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge worker     NULL    0.000
3       system user             NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge worker     NULL    0.000
2       system user             NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB purge coordinator        NULL    0.000
5       system user             NULL    Daemon  NULL    InnoDB shutdown handler NULL    0.000
165     root    localhost       NULL    Query   0       Init    SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST   0.000

# mysql -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS"
| InnoDB |      | 
=====================================
2020-10-03 14:06:38 0x7f75a80d3700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 32 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 4 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 3934 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 3938
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 20530
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 11722
RW-shared spins 4030, rounds 120151, OS waits 3978
RW-excl spins 461, rounds 4074, OS waits 105
RW-sx spins 3, rounds 34, OS waits 1
Spin rounds per wait: 29.81 RW-shared, 8.84 RW-excl, 11.33 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 11691927
Purge done for trx's n:o < 11691927 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 29
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421645436261816, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436257600, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436253384, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436249168, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436244952, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436240736, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436236520, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436232304, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436228088, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436223872, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436219656, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421645436215440, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
93717 OS file reads, 55970 OS file writes, 38023 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 13.12 writes/s, 9.28 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 9, seg size 11, 1 merges
merged operations:
 insert 1, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 106 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 325 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 179 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 21 buffer(s)
Hash table size 6374941, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
6.50 hash searches/s, 11.12 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 17606418609
Log flushed up to   17606418292
Pages flushed up to 17606418292
Last checkpoint at  17606417955
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
12039 log i/o's done, 3.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 26340229120
Dictionary memory allocated 73904
Buffer pool size   1572840
Free buffers       1478380
Database pages     93823
Old database pages 34783
Modified db pages  4
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 93675, created 148, written 32090
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 7.34 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 93823, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       184858
Database pages     11668
Old database pages 4322
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11651, created 17, written 1986
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.72 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11668, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       184576
Database pages     11963
Old database pages 4436
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11963, created 0, written 4069
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.34 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11963, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       185021
Database pages     11505
Old database pages 4264
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11503, created 2, written 340
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.09 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11505, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       184908
Database pages     11622
Old database pages 4310
Modified db pages  3
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.002
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11621, created 1, written 14439
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 3.16 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11622, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       184668
Database pages     11861
Old database pages 4398
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11861, created 0, written 4769
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11861, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       184471
Database pages     12058
Old database pages 4470
Modified db pages  1
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.001
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 12058, created 0, written 3761
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.12 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 12058, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       185183
Database pages     11338
Old database pages 4205
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11274, created 64, written 2639
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.84 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11338, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   196584
Free buffers       184695
Database pages     11808
Old database pages 4378
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 11744, created 64, written 87
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 11808, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=1, Main thread ID=140143358617344, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 1275, updated 5512, deleted 210, read 623592
0.00 inserts/s, 1.34 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 8.62 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of: `mysql -e "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"|grep -vi sleep` and `mysql -e "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS"`

Comment: To see the kernel stack traces of the processes that are in D state (usually waiting for disk), run: `for D_state_process in "$(sudo egrep '^State:[[:space:]]+D' /proc/*/status)";do echo "$D_state_process"|sed -r 's/.*proc.([^/]+).*/\1/';done|while read PID;do echo PID=$PID;sudo cat /proc/$PID/stack;done`

Comment: When you took the first 2 commands (`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`), MySQL was idle. You need to run them while the I/O is high.

Comment: Well, performance is not my issue, I just want to know what's writing. As you can see, 3.9 M/s is 0.76%, so you command returns an empty list. The processes are mostly sleeping oder ideling. If I run this command directly on mysqld I get State: S (sleeping)

Comment: Since high I/O is likely to cause high elapsed time, and the slowlog measures elapsed time, that may be the best tool:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: If there is a large insert/delete/update, there will be I/O to finish up the index changes even after the query finishes.  Cf "Change buffer".

Comment: I don't assume I actually have slow queries, my disks are very capable of writing 30M/s. It's just since they are NVME SSDs, at some point this will kill them. And I'm talking like a 30M/s average 24/7, mysqld is always writing something to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Install `mytop` and point it at the database. That will show you what queries are currently running.

```
mytop -uroot -proot_password -d default_database
```